# Adding prototype function to a specific string?

Tags: javascript

I have a method inside a class that uses lodash's `get` and looks like this:

```
get(path, defaultValue = '–') {
  const result = _.get(this, path, defaultValue);
  return result;
}
```

Assuming that `result` is a string, is there a chance to add a prototype method `isDefault`? I've tried implementation below and it does not work:

```
get(path, defaultValue = '–') {
  const result = _.get(this, path, defaultValue);
  result.isDefault = () => result === defaultValue;
  return result;
}
```

I know that I could just wrap the result in a class and define the method there, but I also want to just write `console.log(result)` to get a string printed on my screen.

Comment: NB: you're specifically _not_ adding this to the prototype (which affects every instance).  You're just trying to add a method as a property of a _single_ instance.

Comment: maybe this can give u some clues https://stackoverflow.com/q/6804370/6442877

Comment: @Alnitak: Good point, but writing `result.prototype.isDefault` gives an error

Comment: @Ancinek that's because only `Function` objects (and classes) have a `.prototype` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a primitive string which is not really an instance of string, so you need to wrap your result assignment in String instance:

```
const result = new String(_.get(this, path, defaultValue));
```

Comment: That works, but it makes `result` harder to use as if it were a string primitive. For example `console.log(result)` doesn't log a simple string anymore. You need to explicitly call `result.toString()`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you also can use `__proto__` assignment but I'd not recommend to do this as it is a bad practice: `result.__proto__.func = function() { ... };`

Comment: I'm going to accept it as it works the way I expected it to work. Maybe someone can give a deeper insight about this solution - I'm going to have a small research on this tomorrow.